# Lock row in Typeorm PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

i am using typeorm and have a entity with fields of `external_id` and `reserved`. as I will have to run concurrent requests to update rows, I am using locks to avoid duplicate update.

```
    import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
    
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    let target_item = await this.assetsRepository.findOne({
        where: {
          external_id: data.external_id,
          reserved: false
        },
        lock: { mode: "pessimistic_partial_write"},
      });

      let target_item_1 = await this.assetsRepository.findOne({
        where: {
          external_id: data.external_id,
          reserved: false
        },
        lock: { mode: "pessimistic_partial_write"},
      });
```

I am expecting `target_item` and `target_item_1` to be different but they return the same row.

following is the raw query i have tried too

```
SELECT * FROM nftassets AS Asset WHERE Asset.external_id = 1 AND Asset.reserved = false FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

Comment: My guess would be that you have to use two separate transactions